# pandoc citeproc from markdown to markdown but render citations

Tags: markdown, pandoc-citeproc

I want to do the following thing:

- Take markdown files with citationkeys in them f.i. @AuthorYear
- run pandoc citeproc on top of it to create markdown files but with the citation replaced by actual text.

Example of what I already tried:

- citationsfile is file containing citations
- infile.md and outfile are what goes in and goes out respectively

I can convert it from markdown to html

`pandoc --bibliography citations.json  --citeproc infile.md -o outfile.html`

This doesn't seem to work

`pandoc --bibliography citations.json  --citeproc infile.md -o outfile.md`

There is a output markdown file, but it still contains the key, not the replacement.
Is there a more elegant solution than markdown-html-markdown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question has been answered [elsewhere](https://superuser.com/a/1161832/387225). The solution is to use `-t markdown-citations`, which means markdown MINUS citations.

From the original [Pandoc documentation](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#general-options):

> Extensions can be individually enabled or disabled by appending +EXTENSION or -EXTENSION to the format name. See Extensions below, for a list of extensions and their names. See --list-input-formats and --list-extensions, below.

Comment: Also can try another format ```-t markdown_strict```